# App crashes when a button is used to invoke a new activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-button

I'm using a button to go to an about page in my application, but whenever the button is clicked the app crashes. There are no gradle builds errors.

In the parent class, I've used this code. This piece of code has worked for me in the past without any issues. Whenever I hover over the button 2, it states that 'button2(android.view.View)' is never used, I've imported android view.View above.

```
public void button2(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, prepo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I've then used this in the Android manifest.

```
       <activity
        android:name=".prepo"
        android:label="About"
        android:parentActivityName=".BitRates">
      </activity>
```

And my xml in the parent class is as follows.

```
<Button
    android:text="About"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:onClick="button2 (BitRates)" />
```

I've used this before in developing applications and it has worked, without any errors or crashes.

Edit:

Error logs.

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.user.name, PID: 3101
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method button2 (BitRates)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button2'
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:307)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:266)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Application terminated.
```

Solved, changes in the xml from

```
 android:onClick="button2 (BitRates)"
```

to this

```
 android:onClick="button2" />
```

Comment: Post your errors logs!

Comment: post your logcat errors @MrPool

Comment: Use onClick like this android:onClick="button2" in layout xml and check

Comment: Error Logs posted

Comment: Why not do it using the button's onClickListener?

Comment: @ReadyAndroid It solved the error! Cheers.

Comment: use android:onClick="button2" instead android:onClick="button2 (BitRates)" in your button tag

Comment: android:onClick="button2 (BitRates)" to  android:onClick="button2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your button xml code to this :

```
<Button
    android:text="About"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:onClick="button2" />
```

What above code is doing is it will trigger the method `button2` of your activity. Earlier it was searching for following method name: `button2 (BitRates)` in your acitvity